# Problem with displaying data from the linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I try to display data from two tables using linq, there is no error, but i think that my data did not get to the view. When debugging the code I see that the correct information is processed by linq. After I run my application, no data appears only  `@Html.DisplayNameFor` shows up.

```
var details = from l in db.LogDetails.ToList()
              join a in db.AuditLog.ToList()
                 on l.AuditLogId equals a.AuditLogId into b
              from d in b.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where d.RecordId.Equals(id)
              select new AuditLogDetail
                      {
                          PropertyName = l.PropertyName,
                          OriginalValue = l.OriginalValue,
                          NewValue = l.NewValue
                      };

return View(details.ToList());
```

Full view

```
@model IEnumerable<TrackerEnabledDbContext.Common.Models.AuditLogDetail>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lista zgłoszeń";
}

<h2>Lista zgłoszeń</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Nowe zgłoszenie", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PropertyName)

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OriginalValue)

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NewValue)
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PropertyName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OriginalValue)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewValue)
        </td>
    </tr> 
    }

</table>
```

[Screenshot of information that show up after debugging of return View(details.ToList());](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulV9f.png)

I changed the linq query to:

```
var r = from s in db.LogDetails
        select s;
```

and every value from the table displayed correctly, but I need to filter data based on another table, so when I try following code, there is an error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Code:

```
var r = from s in db.LogDetails
        join l in db.AuditLog
             on s.AuditLogId equals l.AuditLogId
        where l.RecordId.Equals(id)
        select s;
```

I've changed equals to ==, but then it won't compile.

Comment: Did you declare the model type as `@model IEnumerable<AuditLogDetail>` in your View?

Comment: Yes model has been declared.

Comment: If your model is of type List, then `model => model.NewValue` wouldn't compile. Can you post the actual view code, including the model type declaration?

Comment: I edited post above, please check.

Comment: `DisplayFor(modelItem` should be `DisplayFor(item`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya actually `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>` is right.

Comment: Can you recheck the type of `id`? It shouldn't an object.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing .Equals to ==

```
    var r = from s in db.LogDetails
    join l in db.AuditLog
         on s.AuditLogId equals l.AuditLogId
    where l.RecordId == id
    select s;
```